# WSO2 ESB and JMS or AMQP custom properties

Tags: routes, jms, wso2, amqp

Is it possible to read custom headers/property values from inbound JMS and/or AMQP messages ? How is this accomplished ? We currently use headers for routing purposes in Apache Camel so I need to do the same thing with WSO2 ESB. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this expression to read your jms header :

```
get-property('transport','YOUR_JMS_HEADER_NAME')
```

sample :

```
<log level="custom">            
    <property name="my jms property" expression="get-property('transport', 'YOUR_JMS_HEADER_NAME')"/>            
</log>
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of @Jean-Michel
you have to use CAMEL_CASe for your header

```xml
<log level="custom">
    <property name="jms_timestamp" expression="get-property('transport', 'JMS_TIMESTAMP')"/>
    <property name="jms_message_id" expression="get-property('transport', 'JMS_MESSAGE_ID')"/>
    <property name="jms_destination" expression="get-property('transport', 'JMS_DESTINATION')"/>
    <property name="jms_expiration" expression="get-property('transport', 'JMS_EXPIRATION')"/>
    <property name="jms_delivery_mode" expression="get-property('transport', 'JMS_DELIVERY_MODE')"/>
</log>
```

Result :

```
jms_timestamp = 1637588070662, jms_message_id = ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:283e7b13cbaa4ad0b8bccb2c525b6705, jms_destination = testwso2/Subscriptions/mySubscription, jms_expiration = 1638797670662, jms_delivery_mode = 1
```